# Declare cursor previous and current element by SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have a SQL Server database. I keep data as `int` type points. Then I will do another operation with these ids, but how can I perform a mathematical operation between the declare cursor and the previous and next element in a certain table?

The rough draft algorithm is as follows;

- 16 (1. rows point data)
- 20 (2. rows point data => ABS(20-16) => 4)
- 18 (3. rows point data => ABS(18-20) => 2)
- **30** (4. rows point data => ABS(30-18) => 12)
- **55** (5. rows point data => ABS(55-30) => 15)
- **29** (6. rows point data => ABS(29-55) => 21)
- 32 (7. rows point data => ABS(32-29) => 3)

I will set this as stored procedure in programmability.

Currently only show point data in T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @point as int

DECLARE example CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT POINT 
    FROM data WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ORDER BY DATE ASC

OPEN example

FETCH NEXT FROM example INTO @point

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @point

    FETCH NEXT FROM example INTO @point
END

CLOSE example
DEALLOCATE example
```

Thank you for everything..

Comment: How do you define the *previous* and *next* rows? Remember that relational tables do not have inherent ordering. You need to provide us with a sorting criteria.

Comment: ORDER BY DATE ASC listening criteria

Comment: You really should avoid `NOLOCK`, it has serious data integrity implications.

Comment: i knowed NOLOCK method. same time multiple insert-update-select query protecting running data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG()` to peek at the previous row, according to an ordering criteria, as in `lag(point) over(order by date)`.

For example:

```
select t.*,
  point - coalesce(lag(point) over(order by date), 0) as diff
from t
```